# Powershell select string to find any value on a line higher than 0

Tags: powershell, select-string

Trying to search through .txt files and find line that contain any value higher than 0.

```
(Select-String -Path SADM-COUNT\*.txt -AllMatches '0*[1-9]\d*$').Line | Set-Content Output.txt
```

sample of the .txt file we are searching:

```
Fa0/1        12479523313       18114137          73428              7 
Fa0/2                  0              0              0              0 
Fa0/3                  0              0              0              0
```

I just want to see lines in the file that have lines with numbers higher than 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: `(Get-Content FILE) -match '\s[1-9]'`

Comment: works a treat.. thankyou so much..    would you know how to include the Filename in the output, as we are searching multiple files at the same time?

Comment: @normbeef: Please update your question directly with the new requirement (in more detail - where should the filename go?). Please note that, generally, you shouldn't change the premise of the question after the fact, especially if answers have already been given.

Comment: Hi,  yes apologies..  the solution worked perfectly,  I have found a solution to the other question using Perl.   Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I actually meant if answer _posts_ have been created yet. @AnsgarWiechers' answer has the form of a _comment_, so it's not too late to modify the question in this case - assuming that you still have interest in an all-PowerShell solution. If not, I hope that Ansgar publishes his comment as an answer, so we can get closure.

Answer (score 0):

Check for whitespace followed by a non-zero digit:

```
(Select-String -Path 'SADM-COUNT\*.txt' -AllMatches '\s[1-9]').Line |
    Set-Content 'Output.txt'
```

You don't need `Select-String` for this, though. `Get-Content` and the `-match` operator will suffice:

```
(Get-Content 'SADM-COUNT\*.txt') -match '\s[1-9]' | Set-Content 'Output.txt'
```